# Diffrence between path /user and path /admin?

Tags: path-aliases

Is there a difference between the path /user and the path /admin?
Example: www.page.com/user and www.page.com/admin

I'm asking because I can access the /user page but not the /admin page.

Answer (score 0):

If you're logged in and you have no access to the /admin page then you most probably don't have the right permissions to access.

The admin pages should not be accessible for not-logged-in users, they provide access to the administration pages (e.g. Content, Structure, Configuration etc) per default. The /user path provides the settings for your user-account.

If you are logged out, the /user path directs to the login-page per default.